# How can I create a volume in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker-compose

I have been trying to create a volume in elastiflow-logstash from docker-compose.yml.

I tried adding like this:

```
./elastiflow-logstash-data:/etc/logstash/elastiflow
```

When I upload the containers, elastiflow-logstash drops in a few seconds.

I added the volume like this:

```
elastiflow-logstash:
    image: robcowart/elastiflow-logstash:4.0.1
    container_name: elastiflow-logstash
    restart: 'no'
    depends_on:
      - elastiflow-elasticsearch
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
    - /logstash/elastiflow/conf.d:/etc/logstash/elastiflow
    environment:
      # JVM Heap size - this MUST be at least 3GB (4GB preferred)
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms4g -Xmx4g'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [define volumes in docker-compose.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68647242/define-volumes-in-docker-compose-yaml)

Comment: [robcowart/elastiflow-logstash](https://hub.docker.com/r/robcowart/elastiflow-logstash) is very old and deprecated.  Why don't you use [the new one](https://hub.docker.com/r/elastiflow/flow-collector) that also provides an example of `Dockerfile`?